# IE doesn't open from PowerShell script as a scheduled task

Tags: powershell

I want for each 5 minutes to call PowerShell script.
The script:

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.navigate("https://www.google.com")
```

however, script is executed, I can see blue console of PowerShell program, but it wont open IE to present me a website.

Settings in Action:

[image]

How to force script to open InternetExplorer, or Chrome?

Comment: Arguments: -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -file "C:\bvc\openIE.ps1"
Start in: c:\bvc\

Comment: @f6a4 still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script should look like this (one line responsible for showing IE was missing):

```bsh
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.navigate("https://www.google.com")
$ie.Visible=$true
```

Then it should work (tested on my Win7). Keep in mind, it's still a good practice to be more explicit while defining your task. For example, in current format it'd fail in case you have spaces in your script name.

Comment: thanks it works with this additional line. I thought that it will behave the same when I tested in VS Code..

Answer (score 0):

Use in Program/script field

`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

and add argument

`-File "c:\bvc\openIE.ps1"`

in your ps1 use this command

`Start-Process iexplore -ArgumentList 'google.com' -passthru`

Comment: still the same. it wont open IE11